# Request up to 1 reviewer in GitHub Team Free plan

Tags: github

Currently, In GitHub Team or Organization Free Plan, I figured out that only reviewers up to 1.
Is any way to add a reviewer for GitHub Team Free plan?

Comment: If it's a private repo you are limited to 1 person per PR.